# Start learning Math for all my Physics

Tags: resource-recommendations, education, mathematics

I know Physics but I don't know Math for this physics. Let me explain.

When I say I know physics I mean I know stuff like

- Einsteins Special & General Relativity, Time Dilation, Gravitational Lens, Big Bang Theory, Singularity, Background Cosmic Radiation, Bohr's Model, Standard Model,  Higs-Boson, SParticles, Anti Matter,  Dark Matter, Dark Energy, Black Holes, String Thoery, M-theory, 11 Dimensions etc... etc..

Point being I'm upto speed with current theoretical and proven physics. I've not gone into Quantum Mechanics yet. I also have very very very little knowledge of the math for physics. Like I know the equations for Newtons Laws of Motion. That's not much. I had studied how to calculate gravity, mass of atom, speed of electron etc but forgot all that. I know a lot of Calculus is used for all this physics. I took calculus as well but besides Integration & Derivation I know nothing now. The problem is I choose to become a Software Engineer and have been so since the last 3 years. I want to start learning all the Math which goes into all the physics. because a few days back I wanted to calculate magnetic vortex and I cant because I dont know the math. And this problem is going to continue unless I sit down and put some effort in Math and all the modern physics will stay concepts for me, I need to pass the math barrier. **So my question is where to start? Is there some online course, some books I should go though and outline of what I need to learn?**

p.s. Sorry for the long description

Comment: and easy way I thought of is start studying the MIT course-ware http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/

Comment: How is it possible to know string theory but not remember advanced calculus?

Comment: By listening to the lectures of Michio Kaku, Kip S Thorne,
Neil deGrasse Tyson & Brian Greene.

Comment: Am I the only one who finds it ironic that this question is voted a duplicate of a *closed* question that doesn't fit this forum?

Comment: oh don't worry Steeven.. human prejudice does wonders....